# Basar Bchalav Smicha

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk

Im learning Basar Bchalav now and it'd be very helpful to get summaries of the (Sh"A, Rema) Taz and Shach (Pischei Tshuvos). Does anyone know a sefer that sums them up (preferably in English)? Does anyone have notes online or the like?

Comment: There are  many MB types of seforim today.

Comment: Part of learning for smicha is learning how to learn these essential sources, not just memorizing practical Halakhic summaries.

Comment: A friend of mine wrote [this](https://www.kolhalashon.com/Downloads/DownloadForm.aspx?OtherType=True&File=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8.pdf) really good one, although it's in Hebrew. For some reason the site to download it wants your phone number and email though...which is weird.

Comment: @robev Thanks! That's excellent. (If someone is not interested in giving them their info, the website accepts any info - real or fake)

Comment: @Dov He's looking for English. The suggestions there are Hebrew.

Comment: @DoubleAA He didn't say he was learning it for Semicha. And even if he is, there's nothing wrong with using English summaries as part of their review process. Many people remember things better when they read them in English than in Hebrew.

Comment: @Eliyahu he said 'preferably English' not that it has to be in English...

Answer (score 2):

[A Semicha Aid For Learning The Laws of Basar Bechalaventer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1727125851) is great (get the updated edition).  There is also on [Taaruves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1490460578) and [Melicha](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491246472) and it is in english.

They also have a [workbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1499293097) but I never used it.

There is also [עזר לשלחן - בשר וחלב](https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F---%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%91) is very good but its in hebrew, it also has revew qustions in the back.

Answer (score 1):

A great reference sefer is Ohel Yaakov ,also includes current psakim.

[image]

Sample page:

[image]

Comment: I love this Sefer, I think its the best Sefer for Halacha Lemaisa on Bassar Bechalav Taaruvos, but its almost impossible to find in America. Any leads? (I particularly want to buy the next volume, the one on Yoreh Deah Beis. I have it in PDF, but I want a physical copy).     Either way, I don't think this is what @TwoOs is looking for at all based on his question (although he should probably buy it either way as should everyone else learning these Inyanim).

Comment: https://judaicaplaza.com/collections/new-hebrew-seforim/products/17806533

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where I can buy individual volumes? I already have two of those four volumes.

Comment: maybe try beigelhisen

Answer (score 1):

[Here are English notes that were taken on Rabbi Sobolofsky's Shiurim](https://www.lulu.com/en/us/shop/rabbi-sobolofsky/rabbi-sobolofsky-on-issur-veheter/paperback/product-1jzkgdzd.html) that many people I know have benefited a lot from.

Rabbi Sobolofsky didn't personally review the notes so he requested that a header be added that these should not be relied upon Halacha Lemaisa, but when you read it you will see that the person who took the notes did a phenomenal job.

Comment: What is the format like?

Comment: @sam It reads like you're listening to Shiurim.

Comment: Are you able to post a sample page?

Comment: Here is the PDF: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:81d62dfb-dd12-455a-a796-2b5e0a263590 . The Sefer is only $6.65 (plus lulu usually has codes for extra discounts. Now its 15% off for example) . Rabbi Sobolofsky isn't making a profit on it.

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 0):

The [Ma'areches Hashulchan](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/ma-areches-hashulchan-melicha--basar-b-chalav--taaruvos-121968.html) was a great review sefer for me (and many colleagues) who learned the sugyos required for Yoreh De'ah semicha and wanted to review each siman while remembering each psak. Although it's in Hebrew, it's not too difficult of a read - certainly not if you're learning the sugyos in Yoreh De'ah.

Answer (score 0):

This may help http://www.smicha.co.il/gallery/sikumim_categories-189.pdf

It’s the Yad Hashulchan ( Hebrew) starts from Hilchos Melicha Siman 69  until 122.

Brings all the concepts that come up and it’s in a good layout. I do have a summary of the Taz & Shach in English but I think that was on Hilchos Melicha but will look if you want that as well?

B’Hatzlacha with your learning!

EDIT:

Please see attached document for Hilchos Melicha Taz & Shach summary.

Please be aware of the following message:

Readers are asked to understand that this current edition was the result of
smart-scan technology of the original layman's translation of Hilchot
Melicha, and as such, a number of errors and inconsistencies that have crept
into the manuscript. A brief editorial review was done, however in order to
expedite its distribution a proper and thorough editing was not possible.
Nevertheless, its value and assistance to the semicha student is ultimately
not diminished.

Rabbi Ari N. Enkin, a resident of Ramat Beit Shemesh, is a researcher and
writer of contemporary halachic issues. He is also the author of the "Dalet
Amot Halacha Series" (see:  http://torahmusings.com/books/#arienkin
http://torahmusings.com/books/#arienkin). Each volume in the series
discusses over 100 contemporary halachic issues and includes over 2000
references to the entire spectrum of halachic texts. For further
information, to order sefarim, or to contact Rabbi Enkin:
mailto:rabbiari@hotmail.com rabbiari@hotmail.com

Comment: Yes thank you id like that

Comment: @TwoOsHow do I add a pdf file?

Comment: Upload it somewhere and post a link to it.

Comment: I wouldn’t know how to. If you have an email address I will send it and you can upload it to JSE.